# Ask Drush to list which modules have database updates available

Tags: drush, updating

I specifically want Drush to list, of the modules that have available updates, which of those contain database updates.  Is this possible with Drush?

**Edit for clarification:** I know `drush up` will list all modules that have available updates, yes, but not all of those updates will have database updates that go along with them. I strictly want a list of updates that have associated database updates.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`drush updatedb --no` (shorthand: `drush up -n`) will list them and take no further action.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you.  I looked through `drush help up` but nothing turned up in there, obviously... doh.

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature request; please post it in the [drush issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/drush).  Note that this is not a terribly easy thing for Drush to do; it would have to download all of the projects to be updated and inspect them prior to prompting you.

Comment: I wasn't so much requesting the feature as I was asking if it existed in the first place.  I will add this to the queue though, thanks.

Comment: I was considering how to do this during the pm-updatecode operation. @moshe's suggestion is much better; just grab all of the new code, then revert the modules you don't want to keep after inspecting the output of drush updatedb --no.

Answer (score 1):

"drush pm-update" will give you a list of modules that have updates available.

Comment: You miss my meaning.  `drush up` will list all modules that have available updates, yes, but not all of those updates will have database updates that go along with them.  I strictly want a list of updates that have associated database updates.

Answer (score 0):

There is a drush command that will be better for you than `drush updatedb --no`, as it will not clear the cache (which could really affect performance on a production site):

```
drush8 --uri=www.example.com updatedb-status --format=json
[
    {
        "module": "Metatag",
        "update_id": 7104,
        "description": "Remove the entity revision ID from the translation strings. "
    },
    {
        "module": "Metatag",
        "update_id": 7105,
        "description": "Fix the output translation strings. "
    }
]
```

Documentation is at http://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/core/updatedb-status/